# Why does Vite break useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, vite

```js
let count = 1;
function Test() {
  const [_, setRerender] = useState(0);
  const i = count++;
  console.log("render", i);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", i);
    setTimeout(() => setRerender((r) => r + 1), 10);
  }, []);
  return <></>;
}
```

When I render the above component in a basic Vite app it logs out the following:

```
render 1
useEffect 2
render 3
```

This seems impossible to me as the `useEffect` log must be the same as the `render` log. Its a closure reading the same i variable...

Also how does the render log go from 1 to 3 - it should only be increasing by 1 and logging the new value straight out!

Uh oh I've just tried to reproduce this in codesandbox and it works differently. My question has now changed to how can a basic Vite setup break this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I haven't got proof that Vite is causing the issue, it could be something else. Either way the rules of JS seem to be broken (See two "impossibilities" in the post) and I'm looking for pointers as to how this could be possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue ?

Comment: @JulienKode nope I found another route to what I needed, without getting to the bottom of this issue.